# TVVLC Kit Compile Error

Tags: swift, vlc, tvos, libvlc

When I'm compiling **TVVLC** for tvOS, its **Build failed**.

```
.../VLCKit-master-f246c938d48a315ce29e87b0225587b3f37e258d/Sources/VLCLibrary.m:29:11: 'vlc-plugins-AppleTV.h' file not found
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: @Stefan how fix it problem?

Comment: Have you tried to search for this file: `vlc-plugins-AppleTV.h`?

Comment: @Stefan yes, its not file yet

Comment: You need to provide the full compilation log of the build script, so we can point where it failed.

Comment: @feepk http://pastebin.com/0AFVJf9H

Comment: Yeah, download of a required library fails. Update your VLCKit git checkout.  This is fixed.

Comment: @VLCKit how can i update it?

Comment: Hi Guys I've been trying to to this for days now, if you managed it I have an open freelancer project to achieve just this, TVVLCKit.framework that I can use in a project and archive from Xcode here is the freelancer if you fancy making a few $$$ i'd be willing to pay about $50 https://www.freelancer.co.uk/projects/Mobile-Phone/Compile-TVVLC-framework-MobileVLCKIt/